# Concerned about question quality...

Tags: discussion

Many of the questions I've seen so far are VERY broad, more subject to a discussion forum or wiki than to a Q&A site.

This is a community, so we pretty much decide how to use the tool, but IMO these questions aren't best use.

If you feel the same as me, please exercise the "Close" vote option on these questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd wait a bit, we have only 12 questions, out of which 9 are fairly concrete in my opinion.

Comment: Having waited a few more minutes, I can see that this is working out fairly well ;)

Answer (score 6):

I'm also with Vinko. Let's wait a little while. The website is live for only a few minutes. We had almost 600 beta testers when the site got created. Let's wait for them a little bit!

Comment: my concern with this is that the initial stages shape the community a LOT.  in Pro Webmasters, we had lots of coders used to Stack Overflow to help with this.  I'm thinking, maybe not so many here?  If these are important for the community though, maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm with George, it will take a little while for people to find there feet.  I always have heaps of questions to ask just can never think of them when I go to write them down.  Sometimes the subjective questions are hard to avoid, because of the nature of GIS.  I'm sure the community will be great once people start really getting into it.